# .htaccess Header set Expires dynamic date without Modules

Tags: .htaccess, caching, dynamic, httpresponse

I'd like to set the Expires header for js.gz files. I've added a .htaccess file to the directory containing these files. This is actually part of a widget I'm developing which I will be deployed across multiple domains, so I don't want to use any apache modules which might be inaccessible to my clients.

```
Header set Expires "Tue, 16 Jun 2020 20:00:00 GMT"
```

*not* with mod_expires

```
ExpiresActive On
```

I want to dynamically set the date to today's date plus 1 month.

Comment: Uh, why not mod_expire?? It is _designed_ for this job

Comment: Because my clients may not have permission to enable Apache Modules, given some restrictions imposed by their host, as I noted above.

Comment: Hmm, do you know of _any_ Apache install which does not have mod_expires enabled?

Comment: You know your code uses mod_headers, right?

Comment: yah i realized that after i posted. I guess I have nothing to worry about as long as i use <ifModule> Thanks tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved in comments! Thanks fge

> Uh, why not mod_expire?? It is designed for this job – fge